# Cant build project using Boost CMake vcpkg date_time linking error

Tags: c++, cmake, linker, boost-asio, vcpkg

I'm trying to use boost::asio through cmake and vcpkg in my project and 
everytime I touch something releated to date_time (even implicitly) I get some linking errors releated to gregorian calendar.
Someone knows why this isn't linking?
I'm new to CMake & vcpkg.

#### Host Environment

- OS: Windows 10
- Compiler: MSVC++ 14.23

#### To Reproduce

```
./vcpkg install Boost
cd $MyProjectDir
mkdir build
cd build
cmake -G "Visual Studio 16 2019" -A x64 ..
cmake --build .
```

#### problematic C++ code

```cpp
#include <boost/asio.hpp>

int main() {
    boost::asio::io_service service;
    //boost::asio::deadline_timer timer(service); // this one causes error
}
```

#### My CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.14)
set(CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE "C:/Repos/vcpkg/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake")
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED True)
project(Backend)

find_package(Boost REQUIRED)

add_executable(Backend
    "source/main.cpp"
)

target_link_libraries(Backend PRIVATE ${Boost_LIBRARIES})
target_include_directories(Backend PRIVATE ${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS})
```

#### Failure logs

```
2>------ Build started: Project: Backend, Configuration: Debug x64 ------
2>Building Custom Rule C:/Repos/fridge/backend/CMakeLists.txt
2>main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: __cdecl boost::gregorian::greg_month::greg_month(unsigned short)" (__imp_??0greg_month@gregorian@boost@@QEAA@G@Z) referenced in function "public: __cdecl boost::gregorian::date::date(enum boost::date_time::special_values)" (??0date@gregorian@boost@@QEAA@W4special_values@date_time@2@@Z)
2>main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: __cdecl boost::gregorian::greg_month::operator unsigned short(void)const " (__imp_??Bgreg_month@gregorian@boost@@QEBAGXZ) referenced in function "public: static unsigned int __cdecl boost::date_time::gregorian_calendar_base<struct boost::date_time::year_month_day_base<class boost::gregorian::greg_year,class boost::gregorian::greg_month,class boost::gregorian::greg_day>,unsigned int>::day_number(struct boost::date_time::year_month_day_base<class boost::gregorian::greg_year,class boost::gregorian::greg_month,class boost::gregorian::greg_day> const &)" (?day_number@?$gregorian_calendar_base@U?$year_month_day_base@Vgreg_year@gregorian@boost@@Vgreg_month@23@Vgreg_day@23@@date_time@boost@@I@date_time@boost@@SAIAEBU?$year_month_day_base@Vgreg_year@gregorian@boost@@Vgreg_month@23@Vgreg_day@23@@23@@Z)
2>C:\Repos\fridge\backend\build\Debug\Backend.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 2 unresolved externals
2>Done building project "Backend.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
```

Comment: I think you need to specify date_time in `find_package(Boost`

Comment: I gave up on specifying those because some of them are found by cmake and other's not even though I installed all of them (all boost modules).
For e.g. writing `COMPONENTS filesystem` works but `COMPONENTS uuid` or `COMPONENTS date_time` doesn't. For uuid cmake says that he cannot find it. That's why I want whole Boost `Boost REQUIRED` without any specific components (and in this case, uuid, asio, filesystem and many other things are availabel) - to not deal with this crap and I'm also new to Boost and wanna try out many of it's modules anyway.

Comment: you don't need to put header only libraries like uuid and asio in there

Comment: Ok, good to know :)

Answer (score 3):

fix was:

```
find_package(Boost REQUIRED COMPONENTS date_time)
```

Without `asio` because as Alan Birtles pointed out, `asio` is header only.